# Can single digit 7-segment displays use free digits from a multi-digit multiplexer?

Tags: led, multiplexer, led-driver, display, 7segmentdisplay

The title's a bit convaluted, so I'll ellaborate.

I'm driving a 4-digit 7-segment display with a multiplexing controller, the kind where it sets one display at a time and relies on persistence of vision to make it look like they're all on. It's the AS1115, you can see its datasheet [here](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/588/AS1115_DS000206_1_00-1512924.pdf).

Anyway, my device also has a few single-digit 7-segment displays. Since the controller can control 8 digit displays and 4 of the digits aren't in use, I was wondering if it was possible to connect these seperate displays to the same controller, to save money and power?

Sidenote: Here's my [4-digit display](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/239/C5723HR-1141844.pdf) and here's my [single-digit display](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/157142S12703.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can drive the additional digits as they are both common-cathode.

The AS1115 seems particularly well-suited since (according to the datasheet big print) it allows brightness to be set on a digit-by-digit basis. This is important because the typical luminous intensity at a given average current is not well matched between the two displays.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure.